# Removing html tags from API search result in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api

The result of search in Wikipedia API in React by the code

```js
const resultsList = results.map((result) => {
    return (
      <div key={result.pageid} className="item">
        <div className="content">
          <div className="header">{result.title}</div>
          {result.snippet}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
```

which `results` is search results array, is sth as this image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkwkp.png)

What is the best way to remove HTML tags in search result and have sth like this?:

**Flower**

biological function of a flower is to facilitate reproduction, usually by providing a mechanism for the union of sperm with eggs. Flowers may facilitate outcrossing

**Gennifer Flowers**

that he had had a sexual encounter with Flowers. During Bill Clinton's 1992 presidential election campaign, Flowers came forward to say that she had had

**Flowers in the Attic**

Flowers in the Attic is a 1979 Gothic novel by V. C. Andrews. It is the first book in the Dollanganger Series, and was followed by Petals on the Wind

Comment: Check out [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to just render the HTML you get back from the API. Otherwise, you'll have to just parse it like any other string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use dangerouslySetInnerHTML to do this.

For example:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={result.snippet} />
```